# Magento 2.1 internal server error for specific category when full page cache enable

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I had FPC (full page cache) enabled There is one category containing subcategories and 900+ products. It was working fine but suddenly it started pushing 500 internal server error. I have not add any new product or any major change. so now when I disable the FPC, the category start working and when I re-enable FPC, again internal server error 500.

I have already applied couple of solutions but no success. tried with removing cache at all, reindexing, crons, have check the htaccess also all things are fine, I had try with creating new category but when I assigned the same block to load on that category, again same issue started.

Log is saying that The problem is in the function `getIdentities()`

Can anyone help with this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I managed to solve it by overriding the function getIdentities() in \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View. It works for me.

From

```
public function getIdentities()
{
    $identities = $this->getProduct()->getIdentities();
    $category = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
    if ($category) {
       $identities[] = Category::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $category->getId();
    }
    return $identities;
}
```

To

```
public function getIdentities()
{
    $identities = [];

    if (is_array($this->getItems()) || is_object($this->getItems()))
    {
       foreach ($this->getItems() as $item)
       {
           $identities = array_merge($identities, $item->getIdentities());
       }
    }
    return $identities;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the issue, here is the issue. if we have bulk of products in any category, we can either enable varnish cache or FPC (full page cache)

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7657